# How to create loop in excel for copy paste

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy and past transpose and there is many rows. 
The following code get from record macro, how to create loop upto L1000:N1000 in sheet2?

```
 Sub Macro4()
    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Range("L5:N5").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Range("L6:N6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("B14").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True

    Sheets("sheet2").Select
    Range("L7:N7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=6
    Range("B24").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the paste start with `Sheet2!B4` as the destination? If not, what is the stagger or offset between destination rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are copying across as `Paste Special Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True`, I retained that to keep your formulas and formatting. If only values were desired to be brought across in a transposed array, there are other methods that would be faster.

This starts with the destination as B4 and adds 10 rows to each successive loop; e.g. B4, B14, B24, etc.

```
Sub Copy_From_WS1_to_WS2_by_10()
    Dim rw As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For rw = 4 To 1000
            .Cells(rw, 12).Resize(1, 3).Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(4 + (rw - 4) * 10, 2).PasteSpecial _
              Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Next rw
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I've returned the calculation mode to *Automatic* at the end of the macro. Remove or comment that line if you wish it to remain manual.